# Virtualenvwrrapper problem with virtualenvwrapper.sh

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to install `virtualevnwrapper` but i failed..

It throws me this error:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

I tried like this:

```
$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
...
$ export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
$ mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME
```

And then i run `$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` and throws me this error

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

as I failed above commands, then I try with `$ source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` and throws me this error:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

I tried a lot to do it but i failed.. Can anyone help me in this case?

```
**My OS Is Ubuntu 18+**
```

Comment: Give us more details which Os you are using. If it is Ubuntu which 18 or 16 ?

Comment: my os is ubuntu 18

Comment: check /usr/local/virtualenvwrapper.sh this path whether bash script is present or not

Comment: This file is not present, what can i do now?